# How a 95% full /home partition slows down processes?

Tags: linux, centos, process, disk-usage, slowdown

I experienced a slowdown of some processes on my CentOS box. They did not use too much cpu cycles according to `top`. The only thing I have seen unusual was that my `/home` partition was 95% full.

Could this cause the slowdown of my processes? How?

Comment: Be careful, it is likely to have 5% of space reserved by the filesystem. If that's the case, you are lucky to even be able to log in at all. A lot of processes could be trying to write on `/home`, it would a good idea to check this as well. How do you check the partition occupation? Could you add to your question the output of `df -h`  and `iostat`?

Comment: Could you add as well the output of `tune2fs -l /dev/partition  | grep 'Reserved'` where `partition` is your `home` e.g. `sda2`?

Comment: I moved some large directories to another, large disk so the output would not be meaningful anymore, but thanks.

Comment: And it solved your problem? Would you be still be interested in an answer?

Comment: Once home I run the commands